# Run several PHP scripts from a master script at different intervals

Tags: php, web-scraping

have several custom PHP scripts that I am running from my browser, the scripts will scrape any given URL and return data in form of a table in the browser or as an excel file. ( Optional)

The problem is that whenever I add more than 3 URLs to the script, I encounter network connection error ( Connection reset by peer ) might be caused by many reasons. 
Then, if Data is returned by table then results are truncated and if by Excel file the download file will stop at certain point "Network error"

I am running the scripts on my localmachine ( XAMPP ) and which I have tested the on several live servers and the same problem occurred, however, I noticed that on live server the connection would last longer. I got a warning from the hosting providers that the script shouldn't be run anymore on their servers as it is using a lot of Memory ( +1GB RAM) and is slowing down things for them. I assume I will resume on my localhost the tests.

**Questions :**

1. Is there any configuration / advise that will prevent the Error "  Connection Reset by peer " ?
2. I have more than 80 URLs ( Same domain ) that I will like to scrape on a weekly basis. Splitting the script to 80 scripts ( Each of 1 URL ) and run each one independently. Not very practical, but what is a good method / Php script to run several scripts one after the other from on master script with a time interval of 60 seconds ?

Here a piece of the code where I enter the URLs :

```
<?php 
//to do link
$OutPut_Excel = $_GET['xls'];// 0 web page or 1 output excel
$show_Name = $_GET['show'];// 0 or 1
$urls = "http://www.URL1.com;
http://www.URL2.com;
http://www.URL3.com;
http://www.URL4.com;
http://www.URL5.com;
http://www.URL6.com;
http://www.URL7.com
";
//output excel
if($OutPut_Excel == "1")
{
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-execl;charset=iso-8859-1");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
}

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('display_errors',true);


//output html
if($OutPut_Excel == "0")
{
?>

<html>
<head> 
title>scraper</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>

<body>
<?php
}

if($OutPut_Excel == "0")
{
if($show_Name)
{
    $nametext = '<td>Name</td>';
}
echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>Name</td><td>Code</td>
<td>City</td><td>Address</td><td>E-mail</td><td>Phone/td>  <td>Url</td>$nametext</tr>";
```

ECT......

If script is run as :

1. localhost/scraper.php?xls=0&show=1   | Display data in browser
2. localhost/scraper.php?xls=1&show=1   | Data downloaded as Excel File

Either way is fine as long as Data is not truncated by connection errors.

I would really appreciate any help on find a solution as I am a beginner and have been learning PHP on my own.

Thanking you in advance,
Raj

Comment: 1 GB of RAM? are you sure you are properly managing your variables? anyway there's a config parameter in php.ini that limits the ammount of RAM a script can use, there's another for the execution time. I guess that's what is stopping your script.

Comment: Thanks Naryl, I will have a look at it

Comment: I changed the execution time and memory limit but still have the same problem. Connection by be reset by hosting server. 
Any hints of running all scripts one after the other?

Comment: you could use the `system()` function, to run each of the scripts. It will wait until one script is done to start the execution of the next one.

Comment: @RajaKhoury you have a typo in your code: title>scraper</title> you are missing the start of the title tag. not that it matters regarding the error, but you have a typo :)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question, you could write a loop that executes a second script or function to retrieve the URL. You should have an array that contains all the links to be scraped and run that function or script for each of them, sleeping 60 seconds after each run. This is just sample code from my head, not tested:

```
$links = array('URL1', 'URL2', ...);
foreach ($link as $l) {
  runScraper($l);
  sleep(60);
}
```

The runScraper method can call system() or exec() to run a script in another PHP process.

Regarding the error you are getting, this might be due to excessive requests to the server. The server you are trying to reach may be blocking you after N page requests on such a short amount of time.